# Hide payment method based on product type in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, product

In WoCommerce, I would like to disable particular payment methods and show  particular payment methods for a subscription products in WooCommerce (and vice versa).

[This](https://gist.github.com/thenbrent/6641526) is the closest thing we've found but doesn't do what I  am expecting.

Yes, there are plugins that will do this but we want to achieve this without using another plugin and without making our stylesheet any more nightmarish than it already is.

Any help on this please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is an example with a custom hooked function in **`woocommerce_available_payment_gateways`** filter hook, where I can disable payment gateways based on the cart items (product type):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'conditional_payment_gateways', 10, 1);
function conditional_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
    // Not in backend (admin)
    if( is_admin() ) 
        return $available_gateways;

    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $prod_variable = $prod_simple = $prod_subscription = false;
        // Get the WC_Product object
        $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']);
        // Get the product types in cart (example)
        if($product->is_type('simple')) $prod_simple = true;
        if($product->is_type('variable')) $prod_variable = true;
        if($product->is_type('subscription')) $prod_subscription = true;
    }
    // Remove Cash on delivery (cod) payment gateway for simple products
    if($prod_simple)
        unset($available_gateways['cod']); // unset 'cod'
    // Remove Paypal (paypal) payment gateway for variable products
    if($prod_variable)
        unset($available_gateways['paypal']); // unset 'paypal'
    // Remove Bank wire (Bacs) payment gateway for subscription products
    if($prod_subscription)
        unset($available_gateways['bacs']); // unset 'bacs'

    return $available_gateways;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

All code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

> This is just an example to show you how things can work. You will have to adapt it

Comment: Cheers, Loic! We'll give this a whirl & I'll let you know if I break anything - thanks so much!

Comment: @LoicTheAztec what happens if 2 products are in the card and they have no matching paymenth method?

Comment: @Tobias You can't proceed the order…

Comment: code produced some errors in the backend on the woocommerce gateway settings....just add an if( !is_admin ) in the function and return the original gateways and it works

Comment: @Tobias Yes you are certainly right as backend doesn't like cart object. I have updated the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This code has been very useful to me, but there is an error in it that I had to fix: the line

```
 $prod_variable = $prod_simple = $prod_subscription = false;
```

must be put OUTSIDE (before) the FOREACH otherwise it will reset the flag everytime a new item is executed. I my case, I needed to unset a specific payment method whenever a subscription product was on the cart. As it is, this code will work only if there is just a single subscription product. If I put another different item on cart, the flag will be turn to false again and the payment method will load. Putting the line outside the FOREACH will fix this problem.

Comment: again what if we add multiple product in cart?

Comment: @Mujtaba it iterates over them so it works with multiple products as well